# how to create a custom session for log in user in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to login a user by sending a post request to an endpoint, the endpoint is returning status of 200 means the user information is true, but what i have been doing previously in django is simplify using authenticate method and passing user_phone and password later setting that resul to login(request, user_phone), now I dont know what to do here as here I am getting a response from that api which is just a user id, can we do something custom for this result.

```
user_is_authenticated = res['data']['user_id']
            print('response',res['data']['user_id'] )
            request.session['user_is_authenticated'] = True
            print('response',request.session['user_is_authenticated'])
            return render(request, "app/com-dashboard.html",{'user_is_authenticated':user_is_authenticated } )
```

here i am getting user_id, i just want to use user_is_authenticated just like we do in normal django app

Comment: Why you just don't create authentication backend and then use authenticate and login?

Comment: I have no idea unfortualey. as i don't know much how under the hood things works in django. can you please share a good article where I can understand it.

Comment: Nothing is better than official docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/